# Summoning multiples containers from a single containers using outside data

Tags: python, docker

I've made two python application.

1. a watchdog application, always running, that is looking for new data in a folder. If new data is detected and match all the conditions, it send the data to the next step.
2. a python analysis application that is processing the data and sending back the result in a folder near the watchdog application.

It works well and the watchdog and call several instances of the python analysis application without problems.

I now need to use Docker. I'm learning it.

I manage to make 2 Dockerfile, and with some testing data already in the container, the two images works well separately.

I want to find the best make to make it works with Docker.

My questions :

1. I found on Stackoverflow that if you need two containers working together, you need to define a network in your composer. Since I only have 1 container running 24/7 and the rest is just instances of the same images, should I still make a network ?
2. How is the best way to load the data ? Should the watchdog access from a folder outside a container, copy it inside a volume (defined in the composer file), and allow containers from the python analysis app to access it and write the result back in this volume ? Can this volume be accessible like a regular folder for non-tech users ?

Please, be tolerant with my questions, I'm very new to Docker. Many thanks !

Comment: Is it possible to restructure this application to not depend on "files"; either send data from one place to another via HTTP POST requests, or by passing it via a message queue like RabbitMQ?  That avoids a number of practical problems, and will allow you to scale this beyond a single system if need be.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your interest. Well, the files are sent by non tech users in a folder. So I need to grab them like that. They cannot be sent directly via HTTP POST. Also, I can have a infinite (not really but you get it) number of container for the analysis. Each container = 1 analysis and then it destroys itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your images via compose, they will automatically be in a docker network together. That would allow them to communicate.
Either by IP, which is not recommended, since the IPS are dynamic, or container name, or compose service name.

In the below example, the watchdog could reach the analysis service by the name analysis. For example http://analysis:8080.

You also want to create a volume and let the containers share this volume, so that the watchdog can see the files the analysis service creates, if I understand this correctly.

```yaml
services:
  analysis:
    image: analysis
    build: ./analysis/
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data:delegated,rw
    deploy:
      replicas: 3

  watchdog:
    image: watchdog
    build: ./watchdog/
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data:cached,ro
```

Note that this is making usage of a bind mount, meaning it a local folder is mounted. In this case, the folder with name data in the same directory as the compose file.

There are also options for volumes, you can read about it in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volumes).

Also note, the modifiers on the volumes.

- `rw` means this container is allowed to read-write to the volumes.
- `ro` means read only.
- `delegated` and `cached` are useful to increase the performance around bind mounts at the cost of introducing some risk. You can read more about it [here](https://tkacz.pro/docker-volumes-cached-vs-delegated/).

---

As per your comment, you want to spawn other containers from the watchdog container.

Since you are using already python, you could use the [docker python sdk](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to do so.

In order to make this work, you could mount the docker socket.

```yaml
services:
  watchdog:
    image: watchdog
    build: ./watchdog/
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./data:/data
```

In your watchdog code, you can then instantiate a client like so:

```py
import docker
client = docker.DockerClient(base_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock')
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your complete answer, including the note on modifiers and the link on volume. This is very good. I definitly want to create a volume and let the containers use it. More details about my system.
The watchdog is running 24/7, alone. As soon as he detected a new data in an outside volume, he move it in it's inside volume. At this moment, he create another a new container for the analysis. The analysis (using ro modifiers), get the data, execute the analysis, output the data and close itself automatically. As you teached me, the communication will not be done via IP.

Comment: @Marie, if you want to have the watchdog spawn other containers you need to be able to communicate to the docker engine. You probaby need a docker client and mount the docker socket.

Comment: That sounds a bit hard ahah. Reading you comment made me thing about something. Maybe I should create only 1 container, containing the watchdog (python), and it will spawn instances of analysis script (python too) inside the same container. I will only need 1 volume. If new file detected in the outside folder,  the watchdog move it to inside volume, start a instance of the analysis script (by simple calling python analysis.py with the path of the file in argument), when it's complete the output is written outside the folder. Seems easier, what do you think ? :)

Comment: @Marie, I thought about that too already. It may be more straight forward to do that. If it is possible. It's probably also more secure, since you don't need to expose the docker socket to your container, which is additionally tricky if you want to run the container as non-root. Running as non-root is a good security practice.